# Bilingual or multilingual

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a few tags (namely two) with emphasis on bilingual/bilingualism. However, this is specifically the ability of speaking **two** languages equally well. Should we replace those with multilingual references, to encompass bilingual, trilingual, ... within one single tag?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as [multilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) would cover all tags like [bilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bilingual) as it is for questions relating to the learning/teaching of multiple languages.

I will start with making tag synonyms. If you have a score of five or more in the [multiple-languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages) tag, please vote up or down to decide whether the listed tags should be considered as synonyms. Then I will ask a mod to change directly the tag name to [multilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual).

Comment: You are the only one with 1,250+ rep, so nobody else can yet vote for tag synonyms.

Comment: @wythagoras Not true... :)

Comment: @Hatchet Congrats on 1.25k rep. That is why I said *yet* in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

According to the etymology of the word, yes, bilingual means two. However, according to common usage, it means simply "more than one." Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilingualism) talks of "more than one."

How we apply this is probably more a matter of opinion than "correctness."

My personal opinion:

- At the moment, we have only [bilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bilingual), and [multilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) doesn't exist. Therefore, I see no problem, and no need to change anything.  If/when we have questions tagged [multilingual](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual), this will be the time to determine why, and whether merging or disambiguating the tags makes sense.  Until then, we're addressing a non-issue.
- [simultaneous-bilingualism](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simultaneous-bilingualism) ought to be left alone. This is an [established term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_bilingualism), and it expressly refers to *one or more languages* being spoken as native. If we were to take a stand here, and insist that this should be referred to as *simultaneous-multilingualism*, it would only create confusion.

Comment: But by definition, "multi-" includes "bi-", but not vice-versa.

Comment: No, that's by etymology, not by definition. Don't fall for the [etymological fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).